# Can Blender be used to render 80s style wireframe graphics and animations?

Tags: rendering, animation

I was considering buying AfterEffects before I realised that Blender also does animations, but before I start learning (and please excuse my ignorance) can I create graphics and animations in this 80s wireframe style? Here's a few examples of what I'd like to achieve.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this possible with Blender? And if so can anyone point me to some specific tutorials?

Comment: Yes, blender can render super realistic and retro. Find an example of something you want to produce and Google 'how to achieve <some effect> in blender'. Once you start experimenting and you feel you need help, ask a new question which narrows down exactly what you want to know, then we can give the best answers..

Comment: As someone who is just starting out, try not to think of "if effect X" can be done but rather "how can effect X" be done. **Anything** can be done in 3D (using software like blender). The limit is your imagination, and the time you spend to learn how to do X.

Comment: *sniff* "it brings tears to my eyes."

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112424/convert-scene-to-wireframe-texture-glitch/112453#112453) helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try the Wireframe node in cycles( produces a triangulated mesh ), using the following node setup :

[image]

and with some distortion and blur in the compositing :

[image]

solid view :

[image]

a test render :

[image]

---

another way is to use the wireframe modifier to get the real wireframe, and a simple material:

[image]

solid view :

[image]

the render result :

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thanks for your quick response!

Comment: It works, but may not work for contours or silhouettes, for which you may want to consider Freestyle render, imho.

Comment: An extra question: How would you get rid of unwanted diagonals (in no-coplanar faces)? I mean the extra diagonals in every shape with more than 3 edges (squares etc).

Comment: Freestyle and altering the brick texture in Cycles to use as a gradient map

Comment: Using a remesh modifier above the wireframe modifier is a possible solution