# Convert scene to wireframe (texture glitch)

Tags: rendering, wireframe

I have a large scene with ~500 objects and I want to turn it into wireframe so I can assign blue emission shader and have sci-fi looking scene like this ground here:
[image]

How can I achieve that if I have ~500 induvidual objects
Allso notice how in this Image you can't see the wireframe through objects, this is what I want to do.
I can try aplying black material to everything but how can I render it showing both wireframe and black material?

STATUS UPDATE:

I folowed the instructions from materials you linked me and asigned black material to all objects, duplicated everything and changed the material of the coppy to wireframe. When I go to rendered wiew it seems to look just fine:[image]

But when I try to render it it appears glitchy and half transparent:
[image]

Wire frame is a mix of transparent and emission with factor of wireframe if it helps...

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57134/wireframe-and-halo-together and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56440/how-do-i-save-3d-view-as-a-wireframe-image-blender-render or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56440/how-do-i-save-3d-view-as-a-wireframe-image-blender-render

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38384/render-wireframes-with-hidden-wires/38387#38387

Comment: I need it to actually render solid black objects with wisable  blue wireframes, This article shows how to make only the backfacing wireframe invisable witch wont help me because the black material is non-transparent and I cant see the wireframe in the back anyways.

Comment: Have you considered using [Freestyle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ItWP3lGBGY)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Freestyle.

- In edit mode , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Edge Data, mark all edges Freestyle
- Enable Freestyle in the Render settings, setting line width here, if you like
- In Scene settings, modify the Freestyle Line Set, including only Visible 
  and Marked Edges, and set the color you want.
- Give all your objects and the World a black material, (no lights necessary)

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make freestyle lines emit light?

Comment: They are not part of the main render, they're a post-effect, so their 'light' can never affect anything else in the scene..(they don't have any). But you could use a Glare node in the compositor to add a pixel-brightness based glow, if that's what you're after.